# Solr how to query a field containing a comma separated list?

Tags: search, solr

in our solr core we have a field like this:

```
doc1: "theTopics_stringS":"2,4,143"
doc2: "theTopics_stringS":"34,11,56,73"
```

i cannot figure out how i can construct a query that behaves like that:

```
theTopics_stringS:(IN 2 35 23 66)
```

so i would want all documents which have 2, 35, 23 or 66 in their theTopics_stringS value

what are my possible options?

version:

```
solr-spec 7.6.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either split the content when you're indexing; i.e. index it as a multivalued field - `[2, 4, 13]`, or use a tokenizer that splits it into proper tokens. The standard tokenizer should work for the format you have, where `,` is used as a separator. The default `text_en` field would probably work fine for that.

You can then use `theTopics_ints:(2 35 23 66)` as your query to get any document that contains either 2, 35, 23 or 66 in that list (given `q.op=OR`).